# What's possibly the reason that ajax success event is not being invoke in IE?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter

I came along with a problem in IE, AJAX success event is not being invoke after link is successfully tweeted in twitter. I have this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#tbookmarklet').twitterbutton({
    url: myshareUrl,
    title: myTitle,
    layout: 'none',
    ontweet:function(response){
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: tCallbackUrl,
        type: 'get', 
        error: function() {
            alert('sorry, it fails');
        },
        success: function() {
            alert('tweet success');
        }
        });
    },  
});
 jQuery.ajax({ url: 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', dataType: 'script', cache:true});
});
```

No way it alerts the success message and it didn't fall into the error event too, so i can't really figure out the problem here. This only occurs in IE, not on other browser like firefox or chrome but link is posted successfully in twitter.

I have read in the web to use the `complete` event but the problem there even if the ajax processing fails, it will still perform the function you specified in the complete event so its not really a good idea to use complete.

What's wrong with my code? And what do i need to do to easily determine the probable cause of it.

Thanks.

I have to update my question:

As suggested by Furqan to use crossDomain: true. I have updated my code into this:

```
  jQuery.ajax({ 
    url: 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', 
    dataType: 'jsonp', 
    crossDomain:true,   
    CallbackName: 'SocialMedia'
    });
```

instead of this:

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
       url: 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', 
       dataType: 'script', 
       cache:true
});
```

but it doesn't fix my issue still. After further investigating i have found out that the ontweet event is not really triggered in IE. What could possible be the reason? Anyone encounteered this issue?

In my IE network profiler, i got this result:

http://pastebin.com/fxxCyTSE

But, it posted to twitter. My problem is just when its redirecting back to my website (from twitter to my site), the `success` event is not invoke because the `ontweet` event is not triggered too.

Any idea on this?

Update on this issue:

After further research i have found out that there is really a bug with twitter code. There tweet event is not fired in IE.

Links i found related to the issue:

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/671

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3884

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1640

Comment: You're missing a comma after the `error` function.

Comment: @jared: yes but in my actual file it has a comma. I have already edited it.

Comment: what is the value of `tCallbackUrl` in your code? are you trying cross domain request?

Comment: @furqan: It's link into my website where the tweeter button is in there. Yes, am doing cross domain request.

Comment: @user1149244, then you need to use `datatype:jsonp` with `crossDomain:true` and `CallbackName:[your callback name]` for reference follow http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Furqan: Hi, i tried your suggestion but i found no luck on it. I have updated my question above.

Comment: Perhaps you could improve upon this: http://jsfiddle.net/4pvUB/2/  - right now, it simply returns "undefined"

Comment: It might also help to give a link to your tweet code - is it a plug-in or what?

Comment: Hi mark, were using this http://socialmediaautomat.com/jquery-twitterbutton-js.php

Comment: I think, the problem here is the twitter code itself. There tweet event is not firing in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue on IE is the extra comma at the end of the tweet stuff:

```
    },   
});
```

should be

```
    } 
});
```

IE does not like extra commas

Comment: do you mean on the ontweet event?

Comment: Ok, i reviewed my actual code. It doesnt have that extra comma at the end of the ontweet event.